# IOS: 'Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT' when switching segments

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, swift4

I am following a book called , 'iOS programming 5th edition' by big nerd branch.

This code makes a segmented view in a map view and every time I change the segment when I run it, it crashes with:

> Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT

It may be to do with the old version of Swift from the book whilst I am using the latest version.

Here is my code:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController
{
var mapView: MKMapView!

override func loadView()
{
    //Create a map view
    mapView = MKMapView ()

    //Set it as *the* view of this view controller
    view = mapView

    let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl (items: ["Standard", "Hybrid", "Satelite"])
    segmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent (0.5)
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

    segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("mapTypeChanged:")), for: .valueChanged)

    segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(segmentedControl)

    let topConstraint = segmentedControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor , constant: 8)
    let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
    let leadingConstraint = segmentedControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor)
    let trailingConstraint = segmentedControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor)
    topConstraint.isActive = true
    leadingConstraint.isActive = true
    trailingConstraint.isActive = true


}


func mapTypeChanged (segControl: UISegmentedControl)
{
    switch segControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        mapView.mapType = .standard
    case 1:
        mapView.mapType = .hybrid
    case 2:
        mapView.mapType = .satellite
    default:
        break
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    // Always call the super implementation of ViewDidLoad
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print ("MapViewController loaded its view")
}



}
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: change `Selector(("mapTypeChanged:"))` to `#selector(mapTypeChanged)`

Comment: @LeoDabus [In Swift 4 mode](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md), this will only trigger a *warning* about the now deprecated `@objc` attribute inference and, as such, I don't think it will fix his issue completely.

Comment: I never said that was the issue

Comment: Just changed that after adding `objc` to the func. It works well thank you so much both of you

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `@objc` attribute to your *action method* (also, per Swift 3, remove the argument label using `_` as well):

```
@objc func mapTypeChanged(_ segControl: UISegmentedControl) {
    ...
}
```

As a simplification (and code size optimization), [Swift 4 now further restricts](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md) which methods are automatically exposed to Objective-C — even for `NSObject` subclasses such as your `MapViewController` class above.

By the way, using the `@IBAction` attribute will also get your method exposed to Objective-C as well.

Comment: i don't understand where to add the `@objc func mapTypeChanged(segControl: UISegmentedControl)`

Comment: Add `@objc` in front of your method declaration, that's all ;)

Comment: I did this and it gives an error `@objc func mapTypeChanged (segControl: UISegmentedControl)
    {
        switch segControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            mapView.mapType = .standard
        case 1:
            mapView.mapType = .hybrid
        case 2:
            mapView.mapType = .satellite
        default:
            break
        }
    }
` It stil crashes saying SIGABRT

Comment: @JoshuaGraham That's not what I meant ;) Please see my updated answer. Use `@objc` in your method implementation only.

Comment: @JoshuaGraham You forgot to add a `_` before the `segControl` argument, as shown in my answer as well.

Comment: Actually just checked you don't need the `@objc` but thanks anyway

Comment: @JoshuaGraham Looks like you are still on Swift 3 and that's fine ;) But you will need it in Swift 4. Anyway, don't forget to accept my answer as well, thanks!